# How to get particular position words in pdf using pdfbox in c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, pdfbox

I have facing some problem in pdfbox.
I can't get particular words in inputted position(eg. `x=20,y=30,height=100,width=100`)

How I get words from particular area.

Comment: Try `PDFTextStripperByArea`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Tilman.
How to use PDFTextStripperByArea because I already tried this.

PDDocument pDDocument = PDDocument.load(filePath)
PDFTextStripper pDFTextStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
PDFTextStripperByArea stripperArea = new PDFTextStripperByArea();
                stripperArea.setSortByPosition(true);
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(10, 280, 275, 60);
                stripperArea.addRegion("class1", rect);

Comment: The area stripper uses java coordinates, not PDF coordinates, thus `y = page.getMediaBox().getHeight() - y;` , see also the `PrintURLs` example.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Tilman.
I just want getting particular words from the coordinates in pdfbox using c# .net

Comment: C# isn't supported... as a better explanation: x=30 means you'll get something from the top of the page. Height 100 is about 1/8 of a page. If you get nothing, try x=0,y=0,height=800,width=600 and reduce from there.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I got the answer kindly refer and let me know is it correct or not

Comment: I can't tell whether it is correct because I don't have your PDF.

Comment: Can you please help another one.
I want to find particular text position in pdf using pdfbox c# and then append some text near that position

Comment: See the PrintTextPositions.java example in the source code download.

Comment: Thanks @TilmanHausherr.

Consider the following scenario,
My pdf has 4 pages then the fourth page ends with 'regards' .

I want to put my name below the 'regards'

Comment: I've seen your question. It should be edited to include the code that you tried. IMHO you could reuse the data from `PrintTextPositions.java` to check whether you have "r", "e", "g", "a", "r", "d", "s" on the same y coordinate, and then add your text at that y position minus 2x font height.

Comment: Thanks @TilmanHausherr.
I don't know how to use PrintTextPositions.java can you please give some idea about this

Comment: Oops it is `PrintTextLocations.java`. Just run it from the command line with your PDF and you'll see that it outputs positions. Then modify the source code as explained.

Comment: Thanks @TilmanHausherr.
I want to add dynamically and programmatically. When I input the PDF file location then it will find the key "Regards" and then automatically add my name before the key.

Comment: You only repeated what you already wrote (and which I understood). Your next step should be 1) to get PrintTextLocations.java to work (and when it works you'll see that it is what you need), 2) write some code that prints some text in an existing PDF at a fixed location, 3) modify PrintTextLocations.java so that it finds "Regards", 4) combine (2) and (3) so that it writes at a variable location / page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the answer. Its working fine.

```
public static void ReadCooridinates(string sourceFilePath)
{
  using (PDDocument pDDocument = PDDocument.load(sourceFilePath))
  {
    PDPage page = new PDPage();
    java.util.List allPages = pDDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
    page = (PDPage)allPages.get(0);
    PDFTextStripperByArea stripper = new PDFTextStripperByArea();
    stripper.setSortByPosition(true);
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(10, 200, 100, 30);
    stripper.addRegion("class1", rect);
    stripper.extractRegions(page);//Assign the page to read the coordinates
    Console.WriteLine("\nText in the area:" + rect + "\n");
    Console.WriteLine(stripper.getTextForRegion("class1"));
  }
}
```